# Not able to listen to a broadcast Stream

Tags: dart, rxdart

My standard stream:

```
var stream = (StreamController<int>()..add(1)).stream;
stream.listen(print); // prints 1
```

My broadcast stream:

```
var stream = (StreamController<int>.broadcast()..add(1)).stream;
stream.listen(print); // doesn't print anything
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Broadcast streams does not buffer events when there is no listener unlike standard streams. Declare the broadcast stream first, listen to it then add an event.

```
var controller= StreamController<int>.broadcast();
controller.stream.listen(print); 
controller.sink.add(1); // will print 1
```

Comment: This seems like a comment, please add code to support your answer. Thanks

Comment: Now you deserve a +1, can you also tell me where did you find this about broadcast?

Comment: It's in the code as well as Flutter API docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream-class.html